# Ключевое слово `auto`

Tags: c++, c++-faq

Что значит ключевое слово `auto` в [с++](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%2b%2b) и где оно применяется?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Это слово переопределено в новом стандарте и говорит компилятору: «Компилятор, возьми и угадай тип этой переменной!». Компилятор в многих случаях это может сам прекрасно сделать. Это удобно в шаблонах и для итераторов.

Когда-то раньше это слово значило совсем другое.

Comment: ) язык С++ к стилю PHP ведут...

Comment: @perfect: Ну, зато вместо

    for (unsorted_map<string, vector<double> >::const_iterator it = m.cbegin(); ...)

можно написать 

    for (auto it = m.cbegin(); ...)

Comment: согласен, удобно, но я привык к тому, что язык был строго типизирован, а тут неопределенный тип

Comment: @perfect: Он фактически строго определён. Запись `auto x = 5;` есть в точности то же, что и `int x = 5;`. То есть, код

    auto x = 5;
    x = "abcd";

не скомпилируется.

Comment: @perfect, не путайте type deduction с динамической типизацией.

Comment: @perfect это движение в сторону Haskell, а не PHP.

Answer (score 15):

#### Каменный век

Ключевое слово auto означает, что переменная находится в automatic storage и время жизни такой переменной local lifetime. Другими словами, мы указывали, что данная переменная лежит в стеке, но так как все переменные созданные в функциях как

```
int a = 10;
```

уже и так подразумивается, что они стековые - то это ключевое слово безсмысленное.

#### Начиная с С++11

Начиная с С++11 ключевое слово auto обретает новую жизнь. Оно говорит, что компилятор **на этапе компиляции** должен определить тип переменной на основе типа инициализируемого выражения.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo( int x )
    {

    }
};
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<Foo*>> arr;

    auto a = 166LL;
    auto b = 'a' + true;
    auto c = Foo(3);
    auto d = arr.begin();


    cout << typeid(a).name() << endl;
    cout << typeid(b).name() << endl;
    cout << typeid(c).name() << endl;
    cout << typeid(d).name() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output: http://rextester.com/BNNAL62867

#### Особенности auto

1. Переменная auto должна быть объязательно проинициализирована
2. Переменная auto не может быть класс-мембером
3. Переменная auto не может быть параметром функции до С++14
   http://ideone.com/n7dZge
4. Тип auto не может быть возвращаемым типом функции до С++14. http://rextester.com/AFDFD63587

#### Холивар

**Cторонники**: есть типы данных в С++, которые портят читаемость когда своей длинной (про итераторы std::vector, к примеру) и хотелось бы писать меньше. Для modern C++ в условиях метапрограммирования возможность возврата типа auto делает шаблон гибким.
**Противники**: тип auto бьет по читабельности кода. Приходится гадать, что за переменная и делать лишнее действие в IDE наводя мышкой, чтобы понять что за тип. Такого рода "динамический тип" встает в разрез определению, что С++ строготипизированный язык.

Я же за использование auto в меру. Не надо впадаться в крайности.

Comment: Не может быть параметром функции? http://ideone.com/n7dZge

Comment: @VladD спасибо подправил - жду вас с правками к C++17`ому стандарту)