# В чем смысл использования auto?

Tags: c++, c++11

В сети нашел статьи, например такиую: [статья](http://www.quizful.net/post/cpp-keywords-usage).

Мне не понятен смысл `auto`, зачем его придумали?

Самая большая польза от него - это отсутствие необходимости прописывать длинные типы переменных?

Говорят, что удобно автоматически определять тип переменной. В чем удобство? Это же совсем не удобно, когда ты не знаешь что приравнивается к `auto`-переменной, без просмотра листинга кода и поиска того что присваивается? Указывая тип переменной явно, более наглядно видно что переменной такого-то типа присвоено то-то. В итоге нужно еще внимательней контролировать операцию присваивания.

Comment: Это какая-то доисторическая статья, которая похоже писалась ещё до С++11. Лучше почитайте более актуальную информацию. auto очень удобное и эффективное ключевое слово, если применять его правильно.

Comment: Не сомневаюсь, можете ссылку дать. Я сам доисторический, потому и откапываю всякое такое

Comment: @Alerr, [auto](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/388414/%D0%9A%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-auto) - второй ответ

Comment: Вот Вам 2 статьи про `auto` (в том числе) за моим авторством: [раз](http://scrutator.me/post/2011/10/14/lamda-auto-decltype.aspx) и [два](http://scrutator.me/post/2014/07/08/lambda_auto_decltype_cpp14.aspx)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ну, наверное, действительно куда удобнее

```
for(std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<std::string,std::vector<std::pair<int,unsigned long>>>>>::iterator it = c.begin(); it != c.end(); ++it)
```

чем

```
for(auto it = c.begin(); it != c.end(); ++it)
```

Но вы забыли еще целый ряд применений `auto` - например, в шаблонных лямбда-выражениях... Да или даже простых - попробуйте напишите без `auto` что-то типа

```
auto sq = [](auto x){ return x*x; };
cout << sq(5) << endl;
cout << sq(5.5) << endl;
```

В шаблонах это очень упрощает жизнь, кстати. Просто это такой себе простенький вывод типа. Или вы возмущены и выводом типов, и считаете, что нужно писать не, скажем,

```
max(5,10)
```

а именно

```
max<int>(5,10)
```

(более длинные шаблонные функции с выводом типа аргументов не стал приводить)?

Не стараюсь переубедить, просто привожу свое мнение - почему я люблю `auto`. А вам только скажу - насильно мил не будешь :), так что можете вполне просто обходиться без `auto` - язык вообще не так уж много **заставляет** использовать, особенно нового - в силу обратной совместимости...

Примечание: само собой, все сказанное относится к современному `auto`, о котором вы спрашиваете в вопросе (судя по *отсутствие необходимости прописывать длинные типы переменных*), а не о том `auto` из статьи, которое когда-то описывало класс хранения переменных и никогда по сути не использовалось.