# В чем отличие "под капотом" этих двух примеров создания умного указателя?

Tags: c++, smart-pointer

Вариант 1: с использованием конструктора

```
unique_ptr<TableCommData> ptrData;    
ptrData = std::make_unique<TableCommData>(TableCommData());
```

Вариант 2:

```
unique_ptr<TableCommData> ptrData;
ptrData = std::make_unique<TableCommData>();
```

Т.е. в чем преимущества(недостатки) одного метода перед другим? И какой собственно лучше?
з.ы. конструктор делает начальную инициализацию переменных

Comment: лучше написать `auto ptrData = std::make_unique<TableCommData>();` (если ничего не мешает)

Comment: @KoVadim ключевое слово auto было оставлено в C и его наследнике C++ только для совместимости с языком B. Есть возражения?

Comment: И что Вы этим хотите сказать?

Comment: То, что оно не нужно в современных исходниках...)

Comment: я думаю, что Вы не знаете с++.

Comment: Хорошо, я сейчас задам вопрос по теме. Надеюсь, Вы обоснованно подкрепите своё утверждение.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич Не спешите, посмотрите https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/388414/195342

Comment: @Harry  спасибо. P.S.: Я и вправду никогда серьезно не занимался С++. Немного писал на С и давно.))

Comment: мне уже не нужно "подкреплять свое утверждение"?

Comment: @KoVadim не нужно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Второй способ лучше.

Первый делает все то же самое, но дополнительно вызывает перемещающий конструктор для `TableCommData`.

Comment: Простите, перемещающий конструктор вызывается во 2 способе? или в 1? Я просто думал, что в первом случае вызывается конструктор копирования..

Comment: @Artem.rtv Именно в первом. Если в классе нет перемещающего, то вместо него сработает копирующий, да. Но в общем случае - перемещающий.

Comment: а как тогда создается экземпляр класса во втором случае? Или там просто отводится место и как такового экземпляра не существует? (как в первом случае, при вызове конструктора). Или я вообще несу бред сумасшедшего? :)))

Comment: Во втором случае вызвается конструктор по-умолчанию. Выделяется память и делается `placement new`.

Comment: @Artem.rtv ^ В обоих случаях дополнительно к этому вызывается конструктор по умолчанию. Во втором случае он просто вызывается для нового объекта, и все. А в первом он вызывается для временного объекта, который потом перемещается.